# How to thread a function in python

Tags: python, multithreading, subprocess, multiprocessing, win32gui

I am calling `def balloon_tip(title, msg)` many times in my code.This def displays the  systray notification balloon. I want that any time I call this def, it should process this def in separate process or thread. I tried making this def as threaded, but, it didn't work as it contains registering and unregistering the class of WindowsBalloonTip.

```
 class WindowsBalloonTip:
    def __init__(self, title, msg):
        message_map = {
                win32con.WM_DESTROY: self.OnDestroy,
        }
        # Register the Window class.
        iconPathName= rootLocation + os.sep + d['iconPathName']

        wc = WNDCLASS()
        hinst = wc.hInstance = GetModuleHandle(None)
        wc.lpszClassName = "PythonTaskbar"
        wc.lpfnWndProc = message_map # could also specify a wndproc.
        classAtom = RegisterClass(wc)
        # Create the Window.
        style = win32con.WS_OVERLAPPED | win32con.WS_SYSMENU
        self.hwnd = CreateWindow( classAtom, "Taskbar", style, \
                0, 0, win32con.CW_USEDEFAULT, win32con.CW_USEDEFAULT, \
                0, 0, hinst, None)
        UpdateWindow(self.hwnd) 
        print iconPathName
        icon_flags = win32con.LR_LOADFROMFILE | win32con.LR_DEFAULTSIZE
        try:
            hicon = LoadImage(hinst,iconPathName, win32con.IMAGE_ICON, 16, 16,icon_flags)
        except:
            hicon = LoadIcon(0, win32con.IDI_APPLICATION)
            logging.debug("Image adding fail")
        flags = NIF_ICON | NIF_MESSAGE | NIF_TIP
        nid = (self.hwnd, 0, flags, win32con.WM_USER+20, hicon, "TITLE")
        Shell_NotifyIcon(NIM_ADD, nid)
        Shell_NotifyIcon(NIM_MODIFY, \
                         (self.hwnd, 0, NIF_INFO, win32con.WM_USER+20,\
                          hicon, "Balloon  tooltip",msg,200,title))
        # self.show_balloon(title, msg)
        global sleep
        time.sleep(sleep)
        DestroyWindow(self.hwnd)
        UnregisterClass(wc.lpszClassName, None)
    def OnDestroy(self, hwnd, msg, wparam, lparam):
        nid = (self.hwnd, 0)
        Shell_NotifyIcon(NIM_DELETE, nid)
        PostQuitMessage(0)
        # Terminate the app.

def balloon_tip(title, msg):
    w=WindowsBalloonTip(title, msg)
```

Comment: It's a function, not a "def".

Comment: OK, but how to fix it, is the real thing

Comment: You should be using some higher level windowing toolkit not raw WIN32API. Also, 3 more things: **1)** you shouldn't call `f.close()` when you're already using `with` to open the file—it closes it automatically, and **2)** you don't need to use backslashes where you have used them because the parentheses are already sufficient, and **3)** you should inherit your classes from `object` in Python 2.x, or you'll get an old-style class which is not so good.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not *exactly* sure what you're asking, but if you simply want to run a function in a thread, here's how to do it:

```
import threading

thread = threading.Thread(target=your_function, args=(1, 2, 3))  # args is optional
thread.start()

# thread.join()  # if needed
# thread.join(timeout=2.0)  # if needed
```

Furthermore:

- You should be really using some higher level windowing toolkit not raw WIN32API; also, since you're obviously deploying only on Windows, you might even consider using [IronPython](http://ironpython.net) with full access to all .NET UI frameworks.
- You shouldn't call `f.close()` if you're already using with to open the file—it closes it automatically
- You don't need to use backslashes where you have used them because the parentheses are already sufficient:

  ```
  some_function_call(arg1, arg,    # <-- no `\`; expression wrapped in `()`
                     arg3, arg4)
  ```
- You should inherit your classes from `object` in Python 2.x, or you'll get an old-style class which is not so good:

  ```
  class WindowsBalloonTip(object):
      ...
  ```

  In Python 3.x, this is already the default.